# Swift: Order of super.init and self.attribute in init

Tags: ios, macos, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to init a subclass like the following:

```
class NameShape{
    var numberOfSide: Int = 0
    var name:String
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with \(numberOfSide) sides."
    }
    init (name: String){
        self.name = name
        }
}

class Square:NameShape{
    var sideLength: Double
    init(name: String, sideLength: Double){
        super.init(name: name)
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        numberOfSide = 4
    }

    func area() ->Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }

}
```

I get an error `property 'self.sideLength' not initialized at super.init call`, so I switch `self.sideLength = sideLength` and `super.init(name: name)`, such as:

```
class Square:NameShape{
    var sideLength: Double
    init(name: String, sideLength: Double){            
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSide = 4
    }

    func area() ->Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }

}
```

and It's fine now, can someone explain the principles behind?
Thx!!!

Comment: This seems like a really odd design decision.  Logically it makes sense to initialise a base class before doing *anything* with the subclass, including setting attributes.  That's certainly the practice followed in every other language I've used, including Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're change fixed it is because of Apple's "safe" approach to this language. Any non-wrapped and non-initialized variables that aren't initialized before a method call will throw a compiler error. It's a safety feature in Swift. Basically, the compiler is trying to save you from doing something like this:

```
init(name: String, sideLength: Double){            
    super.init(name: name)
    someFunctionThatUsesSideLengthBeforeItsInitialized(sideLength)
    self.sideLength = sideLength
    numberOfSide = 4
}
```

This method `someFunctionThatUsesSideLengthBeforeItsInitialized` might cause a exception. In my opinion, super-class functions like `super.init` should be exempt from this rule.